# Expected value of a random variable on interval $[a,\infty)$

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

I'm having hard time understanding this property:

If $X$ is a random variable defined on the interval $[a,\infty)$ and $f(x)=0$ for $ x<a$ then $E[X] = a + \int_a^\infty[1-F(x)]dx$.

This is valid for any random variable, then for, say, continuous case, $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$.

Why would we get $E[X] = a + \int_a^\infty[1-F(x)]dx$ and where does $a$ come from?

Comment: Hint: write $E[X]$ as $\int_a^\infty xd[F(x)-1]$, then simplify $E[X]+\int_a^\infty[F(x)-1]dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly standard trick using
$X(\omega) = a + \int_{[a,\infty)} 1_{(-\infty, X(\omega))} (x) dx$
and a little Tonelli.

\begin{eqnarray}
EX = \int_\Omega X(\omega) d P(\omega) &=&  a+\int_\Omega \int_{[a,\infty)} 1_{(-\infty, X(\omega))} (x) dx \  d P(\omega) \\
&=& a+ \int_{[a,\infty)} \int_\Omega 1_{(-\infty, X(\omega))} (x)  d P(\omega) dx  \\
&=& a + \int_{[a,\infty)} P\{ \omega | x < X(\omega) \} dx \\
&=& a + \int_{[a,\infty)} (1-P\{ \omega | X(\omega) \le x \} dx \\
&=& a + \int_{[a,\infty)} (1-F(x)) dx
\end{eqnarray}